# Conditional Compilation Error in Batch Working For One Script But Not Another

Tags: batch-file, jscript

**Language:** Batch + a little JScript.

**Main Idea:** JScript is working for one program but not another.

**Error Message:** Microsoft JScript compilation error: Conditional compilation is turned off.

My problem is that I am trying to get some information from my pastebin into a batch variable. I would like my code to check and execute the code from the website. I have gotten the code to work independently, but when I add it to the main program I get a `Microsoft JScript compilation error: Conditional compilation is turned off` error. If I run the same script by itself, it works perfectly, but when I add it to the main script it breaks.

I am pretty sure that the colored text script that I added breaks it, but I am not 100% sure. *So basically, why does the website data code work by itself, but not with anything else.*

How can I fix this?

**[Not Working Part]** Menu + Color Text + Website Info

```js
@echo off
color 0a
setlocal
call :initColorPrint
call :title

rem ---- Menu Stuff ----

:menu
call :title
echo.
echo (Type 'version' to see error)
echo.
call :colorPrint 09 "%time%"
call :colorPrint 06 "@"
call :colorPrint 0c "%username%"
set /p call=^> 
if "%call%" =="version" goto :version
%call%
goto menu

:title
title CMD ^| User: %username%
exit /b

rem ---- This part doesn't work... ----

:version
@if (@a==@b) @end /*
@echo off
setlocal
call :stuff
timeout 1 
echo.
echo %code%
set "code=%code%"
timeout 3
exit

:stuff
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('cscript /nologo /e:jscript "%~f0" "https://pastebin.com/raw/wAtBQEeZ"') do (
set "code=%%I"
echo(%%I
)
exit /b

JScript */
var x=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
x.open("GET",WSH.Arguments(0),true);
x.setRequestHeader('User-Agent','XMLHTTP/1.0');
x.send('');
while (x.readyState!=4) {WSH.Sleep(50)};
WSH.Echo(x.responseText);

rem ----- Color Stuff -----

:colorPrint Color  Str  [/n]
setlocal
set "str=%~2"
call :colorPrintVar %1 str %3
exit /b

:colorPrintVar  Color  StrVar  [/n]
if not defined %~2 exit /b 
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "str=a%DEL%!%~2:\=a%DEL%\..\%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%!"
set "str=!str:/=a%DEL%/..\%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%!"
set "str=!str:"=\"!"
pushd "%temp%"
findstr /p /A:%1 "." "!str!\..\x" nul
if /i "%~3"=="/n" echo(
exit /b

:initColorPrint
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set "DEL=%%a"
<nul >"%temp%\x" set /p "=%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%.%DEL%"
exit /b

:cleanupColorPrint
del "%temp%\x"
exit /b
```

**Picture:**

[image: Not Working Error]

**[Working]** Website Info Code

```js
@if (@a==@b) @end /*
@echo off
setlocal
call :stuff
timeout 1 
echo.
echo %code%
set "code=%code%"
timeout 3
exit

:stuff
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('cscript /nologo /e:jscript "%~f0" "https://pastebin.com/raw/wAtBQEeZ"') do (
set "code=%%I"
echo(%%I
)
exit /b

JScript */
var x=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
x.open("GET",WSH.Arguments(0),true);
x.setRequestHeader('User-Agent','XMLHTTP/1.0');
x.send('');
while (x.readyState!=4) {WSH.Sleep(50)};
WSH.Echo(x.responseText);
```

**Working Picture:**

[image: Working Script]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to write a hybrid script that is part cmd.exe batch, and part JScript (executed via CSCRIPT)

You must make sure that batch never tries to execute JScript code, and conversely, JSCRIPT must never try to execute batch code.

It is easy to prevent JScript from being seen by batch via EXIT /B (and/or possibly GOTO/CALL with :labels). But the CSCRIPT engine will always attempt to parse the entire script as JSCRIPT.

The trick to a successful hybrid script is to have a line at the very beginning that is both valid batch and JScript. This first line should do nothing in batch, and in JScript, it does nothing except begin a JScript multi-line comment. All the batch code follows, and then ends with EXIT /B. You then have a line that closes the JScript multi-line comment, and then the JScript code follows.

It looks like you attempted to paste a working hybrid script into another script, without understanding how it works. You simply need to restructure your code to make sure all the batch code is hidden from the JScript (as part of the comment)

```
@if (@a==@b) @end /* This is a harmless hybrid batch/JScript line that begins a JScript comment.

@rem ================== Batch code ==========================
@echo off
color 0a
setlocal
call :initColorPrint
call :title

rem ---- Menu Stuff ----

:menu
call :title
echo.
echo (Type 'version' to see error)
echo.
call :colorPrint 09 "%time%"
call :colorPrint 06 "@"
call :colorPrint 0c "%username%"
set /p call=^>
if "%call%" =="version" goto :version
%call%
goto menu

:title
title CMD ^| User: %username%
exit /b

:version
@echo off
setlocal
call :stuff
timeout 1 
echo.
echo %code%
set "code=%code%"
timeout 3
exit

:stuff
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('cscript /nologo /e:jscript "%~f0" "https://pastebin.com/raw/wAtBQEeZ"') do (
set "code=%%I"
echo(%%I
)
exit /b

rem ----- Color Stuff -----

:colorPrint Color  Str  [/n]
setlocal
set "str=%~2"
call :colorPrintVar %1 str %3
exit /b

:colorPrintVar  Color  StrVar  [/n]
if not defined %~2 exit /b
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "str=a%DEL%!%~2:\=a%DEL%\..\%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%!"
set "str=!str:/=a%DEL%/..\%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%!"
set "str=!str:"=\"!"
pushd "%temp%"
findstr /p /A:%1 "." "!str!\..\x" nul
if /i "%~3"=="/n" echo(
exit /b

:initColorPrint
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set "DEL=%%a"
<nul >"%temp%\x" set /p "=%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%.%DEL%"
exit /b

:cleanupColorPrint
del "%temp%\x"
exit /b

====================== JScript Code ======================== */
var x=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
x.open("GET",WSH.Arguments(0),true);
x.setRequestHeader('User-Agent','XMLHTTP/1.0');
x.send('');
while (x.readyState!=4) {WSH.Sleep(50)};
WSH.Echo(x.responseText);
```

I've made no effort to look for other problems in your code. It may or may not work. But this should solve the JScript compilation error.

Comment: This solution has helped a ton. I haven't ever used JScript in a batch file and couldn't find any good tutorials for it. I though your explanation was great and now realize what went wrong. Thank you for not only putting the correct code, but also explaining what you added and how it worked, thanks for your time.